# Why is my script failing w3c validation?

Tags: javascript, xhtml, w3c-validation

I have this piece of code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/jscript">
  document.write("<img src='http://dm.leadgenesys.com/jpgp.lgt?en=P.........TP_Q=&amp;ur=' + escape(document.referrer) + ''  border='0' alt='no alt' />");
</script>
```

and... when I try to validate it, I'm given this error:

> document type does not allow element
>   "img" here
>
> …rer) + '"  border="0" alt="no alt"
>   />');
>
> The element named above was found in a
>   context where it is not allowed. This
>   could mean that you have incorrectly
>   nested elements -- such as a "style"
>   element in the "body" section instead
>   of inside "head" -- or two elements
>   that overlap (which is not allowed).

Any idea what I can do to make this JavaScript w3c compliant?

Comment: The language attribute is deprecated and there's no text/jscript value for the type attribute. Well, there's not text/javascript either, but that's what browsers are used to see right there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple: don't try to validate your JavaScript as HTML.

You can do this in a number of ways... But the best by far is to move it out into a separate JS file, and then either call it from a short script

```
<body>
...
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">WriteImage();</script>
...
</body>
```

...or better yet, ditch `document.write()` entirely and manipulate the DOM after it has loaded.

#### See also: [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unobtrusive-javascript)

Comment: the separated js file worked great for me! since the <script> wasn´t on the <head>

thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Another way to silence the validator...

Put it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
your_javascript_here("<" + ... ;
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

The CDATA part should be enough for the validator, the /* style comments */ are for older browsers which do not recognize the CDATA tag (it would otherwise break the javascript).

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused, Shouldn't it be: 
//<![CDATA[
//]]>

Comment: CDATA sections only work when the document is parsed as XML (sent using application/xhtml+xml)

Comment: These are multiline comments, as in C.

Comment: Miles is right, that CDATA crap means nothing for the browser. And by the way, in real XHTML there's no document.write.

Comment: I agree it means nothing to the browser, that's why i wrote 'another way to silence (read:trick) the validator...' :)

Answer (score 2):

You probably have your `<script>` element in your `<head>`, so essentially you're trying to create an `<img>` in the head of your document, which doesn't work. You need to put the script in the `<body>`.

However, I'd recommend you [add the element via the DOM](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/dom2.shtml) instead, because you'll be less likely to run into these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 2):

How aboout

```
<script>
<!--
var i = null;
if ((i/0) == 12)
  alert("whooo! pack your things, as it's starting to rain cats and dogs!");
--><script>
```

See that the content of the "script" is inside "html comments"?

Answer (score 1):

It's part of the HTML4 standard. You must escape "</" sequences found inside SCRIPT tags.

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
  document.write ("<EM>This will work<\/EM>")
</SCRIPT>
```

Another solution, and probably better, is to move the JS code in external files.

[**Reference**](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/appendix/notes.html#illegal-example)

Comment: That's not the problem, as there's no "</" sequence in his script tag.  It's still true, though.

Comment: Miles, you're right. It slipped my eyes that he's using an IMG tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write("<" + "img … /" + ">");
```

Or:

```
document.write("\x3Cimg … /\x3E");
```