# Odd HTML validation error

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an odd HTML validation error from this piece of JavaScript any help appreciated, I think it may be causing a bug in the slider function that I'm working with...

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        sfHover = function() {
            var sfEls = document.getElementById("nav2").getElementsByTagName("LI");
            for (var i=0; i<sfEls.length; i++) {
                sfEls[i].onmouseover=function() {
                    this.className+=" sfhover";
                }
                sfEls[i].onmouseout=function() {
                    this.className=this.className.replace(new RegExp(" sfhover\\b"), "");
                }
            }
        }
        if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", sfHover);
    </script>
```

The errors are

> Error: character ";" not allowed in
>   attribute specification list

and

> Error: element "sfEls.length"
>   undefined

from the line

> for (var i=0; i

and

> Error: end tag for "sfEls.length"
>   omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified

from the closing script tag

Comment: Dupe/Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953372/why-is-my-script-failing-w3c-validation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Javascript contains special characters for XML (`<` and `&`).
Therefore, it's invalid markup.

You need to wrap it in a [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#CDATA_sections_in_XML) section, which will prevent the XML parser from parsing its contents:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    ...
    //]]>
</script>
```

The comments are necessary to prevent the CDATA section from causing Javascript syntax errors in browsers that don't recognize it

Comment: @SLaks, I was under the impression that only the end comment was necessary, because the parser won't pass the `CDATA` start tag to the script engine (and the same applies to the HTML comments that are sometimes used instead). Am I misguided?

Comment: @Frédéric: You're assuming an XML-aware browser.  IE, I believe, will do none of that.

Comment: @SLaks, indeed, I was (wrongly) assuming that HTML somehow inherited `CDATA` sections from SGML. Thanks for your clarification :)

Comment: @SLacks - do you think the absence of the cdata markup would cause odd behaviour in a mootools slider - or is this simply a function of the validator I'm using?

Comment: @too: It won't cause any issues at all; it just makes the markup invalid.   All browsers will handle it fine.

Comment: @SLacks - blast, I will have to look for the problem elsewhere! Thanks for your help!